# how to make kmllayer event to popup balloon on google earth plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-earth-plugin

I have designed a fully functional map using google maps api v3 however I want to create exactly same using google earth plugin. the map can be found [here](http://www.spectrumasa.com/mcmap)

I have managed to load the kml files on GE - continents and regions. How ever I cannot get the click event to work. Not sure how this work the following is what I currently have

```
google.earth.addEventListener(kmlLayer,'click',function(kmlEvent) {
            kmlEvent.preventDefault(); 
            console.log("help");


            $('#balloon').html("");
            kmlClick = true;
            var surveyid = kmlEvent.featureData.id;

            if(!updateSurveyFlag){
                updateSurveyView(surveyid, updateSurveyFlag);
            }
            console.log("help2");
            $.ajax({
                url : 'http://' + top.location.host + '/mcmap/feed/kml.php?action=kmlclick',
                data : "id=" + surveyid,
                dataType : 'json',
                success : function(data) {
```

Nothing gets executed after the console logging of help. I want to use GE as the performance is much better than GM but only if I use network links. If i used the fetch kml method it is slow to zoom into using the extention as mentioned in this [issue](http://code.google.com/p/earth-api-samples/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Summary%20Component%20OpSys%20Browser%20Status%20Stars%20Internal&groupby=&sort=&id=39)

Answer (score 0):

It could well be that your call to jquery `$('#balloon').html("");` is failing. Chances are that you are attempting to call the code before jquery has loaded properly.

To fix, make sure that any calls to jquery happen after loading has finished.

Also, on a side point, I would try and separate out the calls by replacing the anonymous function with a named method. This separation wont alter the functionality, it will just to keep the code clearer by avoiding excessive nesting.

```
// called when jquery and the document have finished loading
$(function() {
  google.earth.addEventListener(kmlLayer,'click', myEventListener);
});

// custom event listener
var myEventListener = function(kmlEvent) {
  kmlEvent.preventDefault(); 
  console.log("help");
  $('#balloon').html(""); // should work now as jquery is ready.
  kmlClick = true;
  var surveyid = kmlEvent.featureData.id;
  if(!updateSurveyFlag) {
    updateSurveyView(surveyid, updateSurveyFlag);
  }

  console.log("help2");

  // etc...
}
```